# Swift Joining 2 Arrays in Specific Order

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I wrote the following code in a playground and it works fine, but it seems a little messy. Is there a more concise way of writing this in Swift?

I want a string to look like the following:
1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 13, 6, 13, 7, 14, 8, 14

I will not know how many values in each array and the arrays may not be even multiples, but I will know the relationship of 3 array1 values for each array2 value

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  //sample 1st array
let array2 = [12,13,14]         //sample 2nd array

let relationshipInterval = 3
let remainder = (array1.count % relationshipInterval)
let multiples = (array1.count - remainder)/relationshipInterval
var string = ""
var array1Start = 0
var array1End = relationshipInterval-1
var array2Value = 0

for _ in 1...multiples {
    for array1value in array1[array1Start...array1End] {
    string += "\(array1value), "
    string += String(array2[array2Value])+", "
    }
    array1Start = array1End + 1
    array1End = array1Start + relationshipInterval - 1
    array2Value += 1
}

for array1value in array1[array1Start...array1Start+remainder-1] {
        string += "\(array1value), "
        string += String(array2[array2Value])+", "
}
print (string)  //prints 1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 13, 6, 13, 7, 14, 8, 14
```

Comment: You might consider [whether this question is appropriate for CodeReview.SE](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/1168).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers all of the use cases, but using `zip`, `flatMap`, and `joined` you do this in a single step!

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let array2 = [12, 13, 14]

let text = zip(array1, array2.flatMap({ [$0, $0, $0] }))
    .flatMap({ [$0, $1] })
    .map({ String($0) })
    .joined(separator: ", ")

// text -> "1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 13, 6, 13, 7, 14, 8, 14"
```

Here's that one-liner broken into four steps so it's clearer what's happening at each stage:

```
// 1. create an array with each element in array2 is trippled:
let trippled = array2.flatMap({ item in
    return [item, item, item]
})
// trippled -> [12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14]

// 2. zip array1 with the trippled array:
let zipped = zip(array1, trippled)
// zipped -> Zip2Sequence(_sequence1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], _sequence2: [12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14])

// 3. flatten the zipped aray
let combined = zipped.flatMap({ leftItem, rightItem in
    return [leftItem, rightItem]
})
// combined -> [1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 13, 6, 13, 7, 14, 8, 14]

// 4. tranform to a string
let text = combined.map({ item in
    return "\(item)"
}).joined(separator: ", ")
// text -> "1, 12, 2, 12, 3, 12, 4, 13, 5, 13, 6, 13, 7, 14, 8, 14"
```

Comment: That is perfect. I knew there had to be better way. I didn't know a lot about flatmap and am finding it makes things more concise in a lot of cases. Thanks.

Comment: If I want the ratio to be, say 50:1, is there a shortened way of writing [$0,$0...] 50 times?

Comment: yes! `Array<Int>(repeating: $0, count: 3)` is another way to achieve `[$0, $0, $0]` so you could use that but put in `count: 50` instead.